# problem to read UserLoginName of user from active directory on local network

Tags: c#, networking, active-directory

Az you know every user that is defined in active directory has FirstName,LastName ,UserLoginName(sAMAccountName),Email,....
now i have FirstName+LastName of any users on my local network and i want to get UserLoginName of any users from server's active directory.what can i do??
and here my code::

```
 DirectoryServices.SearchResult myResult;
 string filterString = string.Empty;
 string EntryString = "LDAP:// MyDomain";
 DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher myDirectorySearcher = new DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(EntryString));
 string tempStr;
 string[] splStr = new string[3];

 filterString = "CN="+FisrtAndLastNameOfUser;
 myDirectorySearcher.Filter = filterString;
 myDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("UserName");
 myResult = myDirectorySearcher.FindOne();
 splStr = Regex.Split(myResult.Properties("UserName").Item(0).ToString, " ");
 tempStr = splStr(1).ToString + " " + splStr(0).ToString;
 Label1.Text = "Hello " + tempStr;
```

the outPut of splStr=null;
where is my wrong??
thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context for default domain
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find user by name
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(FirstAndLastNameOfUser);

// if found - access any of its properties
if(user != null)
{
   string userLoginName = user.SamAccountName;  // or whatever else you're looking for
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD:

Comment: @marc_s:only with your code i can read the user.SamAccountName from active directory on my domain??i mean with PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
can i recognize my domain??thanks alot.

Comment: @na.farzane: not sure what your question is - creating the PrincipalContext with just `ContextType.Domain` will create a context for the current domain that your workstation is in - so yes, this **is** your domain.... or what are you asking about??

Comment: @marc_s:i want to test your code tommorow on my office and my local network ,i want to know that for my purpose your code is enough??

Comment: @marc_s:when i want use AD i set ip of server pc string EntryString = "LDAP:// MyDomain";
 DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher myDirectorySearcher = new DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(EntryString));
but with your code it's not Necessary.

Comment: @na.farzane: no, it's not necessary - if you want to connect to and use your only domain. If you need to connect to some other domain, then (and only then) you would need to define what domain to use specifically. Giving no domain name means: connect to and use the **default** domain.